# select all not deselecting all checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

```js
var getCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
var i = 0;
function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox){
 if (SelectAllCheckBox.checked) {
  while (i < getCheckBox.length){
   getCheckBox[i].checked = true;
    i++
  }
 }
 else{ 
  while(i < getCheckBox.length){
   getCheckBox[i].checked = false;
   i++
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Select All Checks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">Select All</label><br><br>
     <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hello Guys, I found above code to select all checkboxes and for selecting all checkboxes the code is working, but when I'm deselecting all checkboxes code stopped working and it's not showing any error in console either.

Please help me

Comment: Put i as local variable i.e. inside if and else

Answer (score 1):

You should use `i` as a local variable instead of global var, because as per your function you need to define `i` every time with `0` value.

```js
var getCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox) {
  var i = 0;
  if (SelectAllCheckBox.checked) {
    while (i < getCheckBox.length) {
      getCheckBox[i].checked = true;
      i++
    }
  } else {
    while (i < getCheckBox.length) {
      getCheckBox[i].checked = false;
      i++
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">Select All</label><br><br>
<div>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm afraid why should I use var i = 0 inside the function?

Comment: Because each time you need to set `0` as value of `i` otherwise it will take `6` as default value and all statements will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

Put `var i = 0;` in your function instead of at global level

Please find below snippet for reference

```js
var getCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox){
var i = 0;
debugger;
 if (SelectAllCheckBox.checked) {
  while (i < getCheckBox.length){
   getCheckBox[i].checked = true;
    i++
  }
 }
 else{ 
  while(i < getCheckBox.length){
   getCheckBox[i].checked = false;
   i++
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Select All Checks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">Select All</label><br><br>
     <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset i=0 each time you call the function.

```js
var getCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox){
 if (SelectAllCheckBox.checked) {
  for (i=0; i < getCheckBox.length; i++){
   getCheckBox[i].checked = true;
  }
 }
 else{ 
  for (i=0; i < getCheckBox.length; i++){
   getCheckBox[i].checked = false;

  }
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Select All Checks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">Select All</label><br><br>
     <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simplest way to do this by jquery

```js
$("#all").change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        $(".checkbox").attr('checked', true)
    }
    else {
         $(".checkbox").attr('checked', false)
         }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Select All Checks</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="all">Select All</label><br><br>
     <div>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
      <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
     </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Put i as local variable:-



    var getCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    
    function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox){
     if (SelectAllCheckBox.checked) {
            var i = 0;
      while (i < getCheckBox.length){
       getCheckBox[i].checked = true;
        i++
      }
     }
     else{ 
            var i = 0;
      while(i < getCheckBox.length){
       getCheckBox[i].checked = false;
       i++
      }
     }
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Select All Checks</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">Select All</label><br><br>
         <div>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
         </div>

    </body>
    </html>










    var getCheckBox = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');
    var i = 0;
    function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox){
     if (SelectAllCheckBox.checked) {
      while (i < getCheckBox.length){
       getCheckBox[i].checked = true;
        i++
      }
     }
     else{ 
      while(i < getCheckBox.length){
       getCheckBox[i].checked = false;
       i++
      }
     }
    }
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <title>Select All Checks</title>
        </head>
        <body>
         <label><input type="checkbox" onchange="selectAll(this)">Select All</label><br><br>
         <div>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 1</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 2</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 3</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 4</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 5</label><br>
          <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">checkbox 6</label><br>
         </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we could simplify this logic a little bit.
Look at this:

```
function selectAll(SelectAllCheckBox) {
    const checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkbox');

    checkBoxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.checked = !!SelectAllCheckBox.checked;
    });
}
```

That`s all ;)

Look at this moment:

```
!!SelectAllCheckBox.checked
```

We need double "!" to make a boolean value of SelectAllCheckBox.checked.
For examle, if SelectAllCheckBox.checked === undefined

```
!!SelectAllCheckBox.checked
```

will return false, so code will never broke.
But if you sure, that checked property is always true or false - just delete double "!" before SelectAllCheckBox.checked